# Crash when calling class member function from non-member function

Tags: linux, c++11, g++

In my code I have a class `Log` with a member function `Push`. Somewhere else I call this class function with an instance `pLog->Push` from a non-class function.

```
void some_stuff()
{
    pLog->Push(...);
}
```

Doing this causes a SIGSEGV:
[image]

```
void Log::Push(const char *b)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
    m_Messages.push_back(b); // std::deque<std::string>
}
```

When removing the mutex, another crash is invoked at `m_Messages.push_back(b)`.
After some research I found out that making the function `some_stuff` member of `Log` this crash does not occur.
I even tried this on another g++ version (4.9) and it still happens.

Comment: From what you show, there is no way to tell what's going on. Try to sanitize your memory first and dig deeper. Have a look at the `-fsanitize=address` option of newer gcc versions, or use `valgrind`

Comment: Most likely, `pLog` does not in fact point to a valid instance of `Log`. In your screenshot, `this=0x7fffffffdf40` part looks very suspicious.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that sounds reasonable.. I will check this and report back later.